# Difference between SliderThemeData().copyWith(...) and SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(...)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and was trying to change the slider style other than the default one. I found that it can be done using either SliderThemeData().copyWith(...) or SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(...) and they are working exactly the same way. What is the difference between these two?

```
SliderTheme(
     // data:  SliderThemeData().copyWith(),
     child: Slider(
       activeColor: Color(0xFFEB1555),
       inactiveColor: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
       onChanged: (double value) {
       
       },
       value: 10
       min: 10,
       max: 100,
     ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that if you customized the theme, you need to obtain it with `SliderThemeData.of(context)`, the `.of` method looks up and returns the closest `SliderTheme` in the widget tree. You can read more about this [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTheme/of.html).

The `SliderThemeData()` generates a brand new `SliderThemeData` with the default values because you called the [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/SliderThemeData.html) with no additional parameters.

The `.copyWith()` method creates [copy of this object but with the given fields replaced with the new values](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData/copyWith.html).

Comment: so what is the difference between SliderThemeData(activeTrackColor: Colors.white,) and SliderThemeData().copyWith(activeTrackColor: Colors.white,) ?

Comment: The activeTrackColor is the same in both cases, but the rest of the SliderThemeData is different if you defined a custom theme yourself, somewhere earlier in the widget tree.